# Why does the font awesome v6 light icon show just square, the same solid icon shows

Tags: html, css

My fontawesome code is not working in HTML. I use this kits(`<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/32b2571194.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`) script link in the header/after the body tag but it's still not working, it just shows me a square!

Can you explain this problem please?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Currency Website Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/scss/style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/32b2571194.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  Light: <i class="fa-light fa-magnifying-glass-dollar"></i><br/>
  
  Solid works: 
  
  <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass-dollar"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You dont load the font awsome css.

Comment: @Cédric sure thing... https://fontawesome.com/v6/icons/magnifying-glass-dollar?s=light

Comment: Interstingly `fa-solid` works

Comment: @MaxiGui indeed my bad, I don't use FA and didn't see it.
Because of the "start using this pro icon" button, I guess it doesn't work because you need the pro version then

Comment: pass the class fa, or pass the proper classes in HTML element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont get it unless you get pro version.

https://fontawesome.com/support#why-are-some-highly-requested-icons-not-available-in-font-awesome-free

So all the `fa-solid` should work fine but not other version.

Here another library that make your icon: https://icons8.com/line-awesome

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/line-awesome/1.3.0/line-awesome/css/line-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-vebUliqxrVkBy3gucMhClmyQP9On/HAWQdKDXRaAlb/FKuTbxkjPKUyqVOxAcGwFDka79eTF+YXwfke1h3/wfg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<i class="las la-search-dollar"></i>
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your help. This is (https://icons8.com/line-awesome) very useful icons provider.